# Can someone interpret my Binary Cross Entropy Loss Curve?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, tensorflow, binary-classification

[image]

I am trying to understand my loss curve using : tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()

Question 1: Based on my loss curve/accuracy, would it be wise to proceed to feed it into a ensemble learning model alongside with other 10 similar binary classification model?

Question 2: I would know the reason why the apparent divergence between train / validation and whether is it a good/bad thing or any room for improvement/unrepresentative data

Question 3: (I understand mse/mae loss curve divergence/convergence; are they similar too in terms of interpretation?)

Tried looking around for learning loss curve but only found mse/mae interpretation so far but barely anything about BinaryCrossentropy. could someone help me please? TIA

Comment: It looks like your model is overfitting. What is the ratio between the positive class and the negative class?

Comment: its 50/50 i ran a 20 patience val_loss callback & 800 epochs

Comment: You may try to solve the overfitting. Maybe with dropout or regularization techniques.